# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I'm very new to python, so forgive me if I missed a fix for this discussed elsewhere, but I'm getting the error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'
```

The meat of the code is below, I'm trying to iterate over a list of paths assembled above, taking the value of each of those files and printing them in a new file. I have a list of subjects and measures, all in sep files and I want it all together in one big file of dimension: subjects x measures.

```
of = open(outputFile, 'w')
k = 1
for path in masterList:
    f = open(path, 'r')
    of.write(f.read + '\t')
    f.close()
    if k % 18 == 0:
        of.write('\n')
        k += 1
```

Comment: use `f.read()`  to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
of.write(f.read + '\t')
```

has to be

```
of.write(f.read() + '\t')
```

you need to call the `read` function...